# Screen does not wake to mouse and keyboard, but wakes via Teamviewer connection from another device

Tags: display, wake-up

For the past week, I've been having trouble waking my screen. When I move my mouse it usually wakes the screen, but now it simply turns on the monitor but displays nothing. Same goes with all my keyboard inputs.

At first I thought my desktop wasn't waking from sleep properly due to RAM problems. I did a memory check and no errors came up. Next I disabled sleep and hybrid-sleep to see if that would prevent this from happening. Nope. It appears my desktop simply isn't waking the screen. It was only by chance I had my laptop on and saw that my desktop was online through Teamviewer. When I connected from my laptop to my desktop that my screen woke.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can tackle this issue?

Comment: Which sleep state is it in when you run into this? Monitor off only? Sleep? Hibernation?  When you disabled Sleep, it still went to sleep?

Comment: monitor off was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check this...

right click My Computer > Properties > Device Manager
Keyboards > [your keyboard]
right click > Properties > Power Management

Make sure "Allow this device to wake the computer" is checked.

Same for 'Mice & other pointers...

Comment: They are already checked.