# Monitor shows blank screen, won't respond do mouse or keyboard movement. (Computer not sleeping)

Tags: windows-10, display, mouse, sleep

This may be a duplicate of [this post](https://superuser.com/q/834441/725729), though the answer there doesn't help.

My monitor will "blank" (disconnect-**ish**) from my computer after maybe 2 minutes of idle.

- The monitor light still signals that the screen is **on**.
- Moving my mouse or keyboard does nothing.
- Putting my computer to sleep (with the power button) and the monitor responds showing that it's been disconnected. I then press the power button again to wake it and works normally.
- Clicking the button on the monitor (switching input and then switching back) will "wake" it up.

---

I've always had an issue where my monitor would blank after 2 minutes (even though my screensaver was set to 10) and when I pressed on my keyboard it would wake it, though it would take a couple seconds to respond (and I would quickly enter my pin, only to re-enter it because it didn't all get entered).

Lately (last week or so), it won't even respond to my mouse or keyboard.

Note, the computer isn't going to sleep - I disabled it. Also when it sleeps my monitor shows it isn't connected.

---

My monitor is: *Samsung IT LC24F390FHNXZA 24"*
My computer is: *Intel NUC mini PC kit NUC7i7BNH*

My power options are set to maximum performance in all.

Comment: Fairly sure its a nuc/intel problem. The gpu/driver is what takes care of displaying stuff on the monitor. You can make sure Windows is updated and the gpu driver is updated. I think besides that you need to talk to intel. I do not think this is a monitor problem but maybe its possible. Testing a 2nd monitor would answer that.

Comment: @CmosBattery I'm assuming it's related to my computer, because I've always had the issue with the Mouse and Keyboard delay after only a couple minutes of inactivity.

Comment: Well, you would have to ask if they all do that of that product. When you resume/go to login or whatever there's going to be some point where the accessories input might get delayed.. if the computer is busy.

Comment: Maybe you should check for a bios update or switch out the hdd/ssd and try a new os install. For all I know you need it. The accessories are attached vis usb which is bios/hardware/driver. And then you have possible os problems after that.

Comment: I recently updated bios, I have an ssd. Entire build is less than a year old. :S

Comment: Then it seems like a nuc/intel or os bug. Your going to probably need more info to figure it out but digging deeper. Course, maybe the bios update has a bug - it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your HDMI firmware.  This is separate from the BIOS firmware and this update is not detected by Intel's driver update utility.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000024118/mini-pcs/intel-nuc-kits.html